# Move marker on click

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am creating a Leaflet-map, where I would like to move the marker by 1) drag and 2) mouse click. The coordinates of `'dragend'` or mouse click are written to 'latitude' and 'longitude'. The drag is all well and good, but I am struggling with onclick.

The overall aim is to make the map more suitable for smart phone users.

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/oskjerv/pjgucx75

Docs: https://leafletjs.com/download.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the lalng when you click on the marker use this:

```
marker.on('dragend click', function (e) {
  document.getElementById('latitude').value = marker.getLatLng().lat;
  document.getElementById('longitude').value = marker.getLatLng().lng;
});
```

if you want the latlng of the marker when you click on the map:

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
  document.getElementById('latitude').value = marker.getLatLng().lat;
  document.getElementById('longitude').value = marker.getLatLng().lng;
});
```

if you want the latlng of the map where you clicked:

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
  document.getElementById('latitude').value = e.latlng.lat;
  document.getElementById('longitude').value = e.latlng.lng;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. ```e.latlng.lat;``` and ```e.latlng.lat;``` is what I was looking for, in addition to ```marker.setLatLng([lat, lon]).update();``` to update the position of the marker.

Comment: you don't need to call `.update()`. The marker automaticly change the position when `marker.setLatLng([lat, lon])` is called

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have got a mouse click event code like dragging code.

```
marker.on('dragend', function (e) {
  document.getElementById('latitude').value = marker.getLatLng().lat;
  document.getElementById('longitude').value = marker.getLatLng().lng;
  //Confirmit.page.getQuestion('R3QX_pin_lat').setValue(marker.getLatLng().lat);
  //Confirmit.page.getQuestion('R3QX_pin_lng').setValue(marker.getLatLng().lng);
});
```

You can write mouse click code similar to drag code

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
  document.getElementById('latitude').value = marker.getLatLng().lat;
  document.getElementById('longitude').value = marker.getLatLng().lng;
});
```